# MVC Web App using Web API do not work after deploying on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have created Web application using asp.net MVC architecture.
I have used Web API for getting data from database. Both Web application and Web API are in same project. I have not published Web API separately on IIS.

When I am debugging or running the application through Visual studio it works properly. I have used below code to get data from Web API URL

```
 TODOINfo[] lstToDoInfo = httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:65373/api/RESTApi").Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<TODOINfo[]>().Result;
```

In Above function I am passing url which consist of localhost plus fixed port number. Above code is working fine when running through in Visual studio.

I have published the same code on IIS by doing below changes.

```
TODOINfo[] lstToDoInfo = httpClient.GetAsync("http://" + sBaseUrl + "/api/RESTApi").Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<TODOINfo[]>().Result;
```

sBaseUrl value is "localhost".

After Browsing the application on internet explorer getting following error.

```
No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'TODOINfo[]' from content with media type 'text/html'.
```

Any information or suggestion regarding above problem is highly appreciate.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to deploy Web API on IIS. As I am new to IIS configuration. Please give the reference link for it.

Comment: I have not read completely, but I am pretty sure this will give you what you need:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323972
let me know if you encounter further problems and I'll walk you through it, Later.

Comment: On second thought Because your API is in the same project, though, you are probably better off keeping it all under the same WebApp in IIS. but you will have to change the baseURL to whatever the host + site:

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. I will go through it. I just want to confirm that after publishing application from Visual studio still its need to configure it on IIS.

Comment: try changing sBaseURL to: "localhost/" + yourwebsite

Comment: Thanks for the support. Its work for me.... :)

Comment: Glad It worked for you I will remove my previous comments as they are not necessary and Will put the my last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `sBaseURL` to `"localhost/"` +*yourwebsite*

another option would be to change: `sBaseURL` to:  *servername/yourwebsite*